# Can we trim all the variables we are using in javascript implicitly?

Tags: javascript

I have to explicitly use trim() for too many variables. Is there anyway I can apply trim to all the string values in code without calling trim explicitly?

**Note:**
I asked this question out of curiosity to find if there is a way or possibility to do so. Even I dont want to apply trim in all the scenarios. But yes I've to use trim for all the literals and variables I use in an app(I've such a req). So wanted to know if there is a common place where I can change instead of missing few places.

Comment: did not get your question

Comment: I'd start by asking *why* you have to trim that many strings…?

Comment: I tried some black magic, but even overriding `String.prototype.valueOf()` does not give the expected results (it doesn't work with literals).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Literals or any other primitives.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's nothing in JavaScript's strings that will globally enable automatic whitespace trimming for you. You'll have to do it when/where required, which should typically be only a few places (e.g., reading from inputs).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a cool hack. would not recommend:

```
String.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  return this.trim();
};

'query' + (new String(' asdf ')); // "queryasdf"
```

Comment: The **vast** majority of strings in JavaScript programs are string primitives, not string objects; this doesn't do anything to ensure those are automatically trimmed, and so doesn't save any effort vs. `trim`. Even with the `valueOf` definition above, `var a = "foo "; var b = " bar"; console.log(a + b);` yields `"foo  bar"`

Comment: ya.. so cool.. will try this. But will this work on literals as  Frédéric Hamidi mentioned?

Comment: No to literals. You can't change the 'valueOf' a primitive value. There's reasons why not to use this even for String objects, like it doesn't update the length property or affect accesses by index. But it's a cool hack that does "automatically truncate" Strings

Comment: @Priya: No, it will not.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thank u so much.

Comment: And by god, even if that *did* work for literals… **this affects all strings!** You are mad if you think that automagically and silently trimming all strings in all circumstances is a good idea. You'll create a whole host of new intractable bugs.

Comment: :) if it was a good idea i wouldn't say it's a non-recommended hack. what you described is the scenario being asked for, though.

Comment: @William B Yes.. Thats the scenario I asked. Thought its not recommended and I dont want to use it in all the scenarios. But I've such a need in one app I'm developing and I was curious to find if there is any possibility. If its not a common situation or people dont prefer it, I dont know why people or downvoting it.

Comment: @deceze I want something like that to affect all string in a certain application alone. Thats why I asked. Even I dont prefer it, but i've a need. So if something like that existed, I would have been grateful. Nobody here wanted to trim all String in all the circumstance.